# Why do I get an error whenever I try to update using Kali Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux

The error is explained via Photo below
[image: The Images are attached for reference]

I am a newbie to Kali Linux and couldn't get around this, so your help would be very beneficial.

Comment: You have the literal line `echo ...` in there, which should have been an echo to that file, not a literal string to put in there.

Comment: It appears that you followed some instructions incorrectly.  You appear to have put the command that you are supposed to run inside the sources.list.  Perhaps Kali Linux isn’t an ideal distro for learning Linux?

Comment: Please post text as text. So that it is accessible. e.g. Big enough to read, readable by blind people, searchable, …

Comment: How much experience do you have with other Gnu/Linuxes?

Answer (score 2):

Lines #1 and #2 in the sources list file are offensive. Edit the file, and leave the following line (remove the rest):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

The line under Additional sources is OK. You can leave it there.

Comment: How to fix it ?

Comment: I edited the answer with a solution

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite explicit: The first line in `sources.list` contains the word *echo*. This is a syntax error.  In fact, the file looks quite jumbled. After fixing the first line, you will have more work to do.

Comment: Sir, Can you put some more light onto the Topic, specifically on how to resolve this issue ? As I am new here and still learning. Help much appreciated.

Comment: @ShlokBharadwaj I suggest you read this: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Comment: @ShlokBharadwaj [please don't use Kali if you are new](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/22222). Kali is not a normal operating system. It is a tool designed for experts and should only be used by experts. _Anything_ you can do in Kali, you can also do with a normal linux, so please use a regular Linux while you're learning. If you don't know how to resolve a problem as simple as this, you really really shouldn't be using Kali. What you are doing is like trying to learn how to drive on a formula one car.

Comment: Remove all the lines that contain *tor* and you should be fine. However, if you are unable to understand and fix this issue on your own, you won't have much fun with Kali and stumble from error to error. I suggest you first invest some time learning the basics of Linux, in particular Debian.